# Port forwarding

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, port-forwarding

I am trying to forward a port for making a server on [teeworlds](https://www.teeworlds.com/) game.
i use simple port forwarding program using [this tutorial](https://www.teeworlds.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=7947) but failed :

[image: simple port forwarding error]

Then i tried to do it from my router configuration using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKKJLCdnhyg). it was done without errors as seen here :

[image: router port forwarding]

but when i use [can you see me site](http://www.canyouseeme.org/), it gave me this :

[image: can u see me report]

and the port wasn't opened i tried it.
So What is happening ?

BTW : My router type is tp-link td854w.

Comment: Can you access the server from the LAN side of the router?

Comment: If u mean accessing the server from the LAN side of the game then what is this all about ? i want to share this server on the internet side of the game.

Comment: If you can't access to the server from another computer on the LAN, it means you have a problem with your computer configuration, however if you can, it's a network problem.

Comment: I can access it from another computer on the LAN but i don't want this i want it to be public server for everyone .

Comment: Is that program/service actually listening on that port on your computer? Have you verified that with netstat?

Comment: no, how to do it ??

Comment: Command prompt as admin -> `netstat -ab`

Answer (score 1):

You've completed the tutorial correctly, but you are missing this:

In order for Port Forwarding to work, the computer looking for the port must be a static IP Address.  Is the address of your PC 192.168.1.103??  Also Change Protocol to TCP/UDP as ssssteffff suggests

Comment: I tried static IP but still not working .

Comment: Please verify your Static IP using [this link](http://portforward.com/networking/static-win7.htm)

Comment: The same, Not working .

Comment: What is the output of ping 127.0.0.1:8303?

Comment: Re: Link, I see nothing...

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/ojq2h7jjamqpdzz/ping%20result.png

Comment: Try Pinging 127.0.0.1

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/tomg2ob759w1yy9/ping%20result%202.png

Answer (score 0):

I have three suggestions:

- Do you have a firewall on computer? If so (windows' one or third party FW), try to open the port.
- Change 8303:8303 to 8303 (don't need a range here) in your router configuration.
- You opened UDP port, try to open TCP port instead / as well.

Tell me if it helps.

Comment: After i saw your answer :
- I turn windows firewall off but not working also .
- The range in the picture not given by me i just write 8303 but there must be a port range for the router so the router make it 8303:8303 alone .
- This game servers must use UDP ports only .

Comment: Can you provide output of `ipconfig` and `telnet localhost 8303` from your computer, and `telnet <computer_LAN_IP> 8303` from any other computer on your local network, please?

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect port forwarding to work if the port you're trying to forward to on the server isn't in a listening state?

Q: How to do it?

A: Install the program/service on the server.

Comment: It is running but the port not opened